# R qplot don't understands 'method' parameter

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to use the `qplot` function including the `ggplot2` library but when I perform the plot, it warns the next:

```
qplot(carat, price, data=diamonds, geom=c("point", "smooth"), method="lm")
Warning: Ignoring unknown parameters: method
```

If watched in a post that it could be cause of library versions, but I haven't got it.

My software versions are:

- RStudio 1.1.383
- R:       3.4.3
- ggplot2: 3.4.3
- mgcv:    3.4.3
- MacOS X 10.12.6 (High Sierra)

Comment: There is no mention of the `method=` parameter in the `qplot` help page. Is there a reason you think that parameter exists? What do you expect that parameter to do? Also `qplot` is being phased out. Better to use proper `ggplot()` commands and geoms.

Comment: In older versions is used, but I don't know if it doesn't run due to version or due to another issue.

Comment: You get the warning because `geom_point` has no parameter called `method`. This works `qplot(mpg, wt, data = mtcars, geom = c("point", "smooth"), method = "lm", se = FALSE)`. I agree with @MrFlick though that you better use `ggplot()`

Answer (score 2):

If `qplot` did support the `method=` parameter, it was in the distant past. Better to just use proper `ggplot` commands to make your plot.

```
ggplot(diamonds, aes(carat, price)) + 
  geom_point() + 
  geom_smooth(method="lm")
```